# Windowsデフォルトのタスクバーを置き換えるソフトを作るため、起動中のウインドウのアイコン・タイトルを取得するAPI

Tags: c#, windows, winapi

Windows 11のタスクバーは起動しているアプリが多くなると「…」の中に隠れてしまい多段表示もできず、「タスクバーを改造するソフト(ラベルを非表示にしてかつアイコンを分離する)」もいくつか試してみましたが動作がおかしくなるようなので、いっそのこと「起動中のウインドウ一覧を表示するソフト」を作りたいと考えています(スタートメニューやシステムトレイなどの機能は無し)。
「起動中のウインドウのタイトル・アイコン一覧」を取得するAPIはあるでしょうか？
言語はC#, Java, Pythonなどが望ましいです。
もし既にそういうソフトがあるのなら(プログラミング関連の質問では無くなってしまいますが)教えてください。

Comment: こんな記事が取っ掛かりになるでしょう。[画面上のすべてのウィンドウとそのタイトルを列挙する](https://dobon.net/vb/dotnet/process/enumwindows.html) ソフトウェアとしてはこんなもの。[システムで開かれているウィンドウの詳細情報を一覧できる「GUIPropView」](https://forest.watch.impress.co.jp/docs/review/1035846.html), [GUIPropView v1.26](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gui_prop_view.html), [プロセス エクスプローラー V17.05](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)

Comment: @kunif ありがとうございます。ただProcessの「アイコン」を取得するメソッドはわからないでしょうか？ GUIPropViewなどはアイコンも表示してますが、ソースコードが公開されてないのでどうやって取得しているかがわかりません。

Comment: この記事やその中の紹介リンク先あたりでしょうか。[Getting the icon associated with a running application](https://stackoverflow.com/q/304109/9014308)

Comment: ウインドウが使用しているアイコンは WM_GETICON メッセージ、失敗したら GetClassLongPtr で取得できるようです。

「WM_GETICON メッセージ」
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-geticon

「GetClassLongPtrW 関数 」
https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclasslongptrw

取得したアイコンハンドルは用済みになったら DestroyIcon で削除してください。

Answer (score 0):

> もし既にそういうソフトがあるのなら(プログラミング関連の質問では無くなってしまいますが)教えてください。

[Win] + [Tab] キーで起動できるタスクビューや、[Alt] + [Tab] キーでのウインドウ一覧では、要件を満たすことはできないですか？

Comment: 個人的にはウインドウの一覧よりアイコンが並んでる方が選択しやすい感じですね(特に使うソフトが決まってる場合)。ただ並行して使うことも考えてみます。